# Team fortress 2 black screen

Tags: steam

When I launch TF2 through steam all i see is a black screen.  I am running 12.04 on an IBM thinkpad T42.

I have already tried adding

```
export LANG=C
export LC_NUMERIC=POSIX
export force_s3tc_enable=true
```

to `/usr/bin/steam`.

I am in windowed mode, I had the same problems when I was in full-screen.  Here are the start up options I had on TF2

```
-window -dxlevel 85 -console -nojoy
```

output of lspci, this is the the full output just the output about graphics card

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV200 [Mobility Radeon 7500]
```

When I go to Dash ---> Details
it says my graphics are

```
R100 (RV200 4C57) x86/MMX/SSE2 TCL DRI2
```

Here is a question about installing drivers for my graphics card. [How do I install the drivers for my Mobility Radeon ATI card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257143/how-do-i-install-the-drivers-for-my-mobility-radeon-ati-card/259445#259445)

Comment: Hi,what kind of video card are you using. If you have an nvida or ATI card, make sure you use the nvidia binary drivers and not noveau.

Comment: @ SirSid I think I have an ATI card when I go to dash--> details  it says my graphics are R100 (RV200 4C57) x86/MMX/SSE2 TCL DRI2 How do I see if I am using nvidia binary drivers

Comment: When I go to additional drivers, it says there are no additional drivers in use in the system.

Comment: try to move to textual mode and then back to graphic, helped me in another game. Do you hear the game while you have black screen? I did. 

read the follwong till the end before you try it, you shold know how to get back to graphic-mode (:
To move to textual-mode, press Ctrl+Alt+F1, than press Ctrl+Alt+F7 (may be also F8).

Comment: When I started the game I heard some sounds at the beginning that I thought were the start up sound when I went to text based mode and back to graphical mode the game stayed black.

Comment: Does it happens with other games?
And try to use a pririty driver. Which company does your G.card belongs? nvidia? ATI? else? something unknown?
run "lepci" in termunal (without ""). Post the output in your question-You can edit it (:

Comment: I don't know if any other games work, I only have tf2 installed.

Comment: Graphic card company?

Comment: I think it is ADM / ATI 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV200 [Mobility Radeon 7500]

Comment: oh, ATI. Do you have an Option ti install a pririty driver?
System Settings > Additional Drivers

Comment: I don't have the option to add proprietary drivers it says no proprietary drivers are in use in this system and there are no ones to add.

Comment: I see. I knows that ATI gives some drivers at their site, but I only know how to install a nvidia one. create a new question, and give here a link. ask how to install an ATI driver of your card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need OpenGL 3.0 to run TF2.

Answer (score 0):

I've had that same problem on an i3 desktop with Intel graphics. Sound was fine but the screen was all black. Simply reinstalling Ubuntu solved the problem. I know this is a harsh solution, but if your system has gone through many Ubuntu versions as mine had, some configurations might have gone off and the most sane thing you can do is a fresh install. Ironically, AMD cards are trickier to configure on Linux systems than nVidia ones.