# How do I install the drivers for my Mobility Radeon ATI card?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics

On this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257025/team-fortress-2-black-screen)  I figured out that i needed to install drivers for my graphics card.  The output of `lspci` says I have `01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV200 [Mobility Radeon 7500]`  and in Dash > Detail says my graphics are `R100 (RV200 4C57) x86/MMX/SSE2 TCL DRI2`  How do I install the drivers for my card?

I think I need the drivers because I am trying to get TF2 working which I asked about with this question [Team fortress 2 black screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257025/team-fortress-2-black-screen)

Comment: you forgot giving a link (:

Comment: I have a link in first sentence

Comment: I ment in the previos ques', so i'll be able to find this one (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here: [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

an answer from this site (:

everythink is there, just read it all and you'll get it, plz read all and read good.
if you really can't understand it, ask here what you need.

for a case I will forget to look here, here is my email:
yinonzadok@gmail.com

Comment: did you see it?